# Get recent price from exchange web page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am self-learning on python and currently trying to get a crypto recent price from Binance (https://www.binance.com/en/trade/LTC_USDT). the Html of the price is shown in the following figure:[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VL7o.png)

the Html code shown in the image above is located here on the website:[code location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i672q.png)

as you can see the price of LTC (currently around $43) is mentioned in two places in the Html code.

The **1st location** has its class address changes between 3 address depending on the text color based on the price movement as follows:

Red text (price down)>>>>>  class="sc-1p4en3j-3 sc-1p4en3j-5 jFILqo"

Green text (price up)>>>>>  class="sc-1p4en3j-3 sc-1p4en3j-4 kZlsgN"

white text (no cgange)>>>>  class="sc-1p4en3j-3 sc-1p4en3j-6 czKdcJ"

The **2nd price location** has its class address **fixed**, but it contains the $ sign.

*I want to get the stock price and store so I could do math with later*. I tried using both text locations to get the price. my code:

```
url= "https://www.binance.com/en/trade/LTC_USDT"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
```

tried to get the price from all classes in location 1:

```
newprice= soup.find('span', class_ = 'sc-1p4en3j-3 sc-1p4en3j-5 jFILqo')
newprice1= soup.find('span', class_ = 'sc-1p4en3j-3 sc-1p4en3j-4 kZlsgN')
newprice2= soup.find('span', class_ = 'sc-1p4en3j-3 sc-1p4en3j-6 czKdcJ')

print (str(newprice))
print (str(newprice1))
print (str(newprice2))
```

if I add `.text` to the 1st three lines above. it tells me: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

tried to get it from location 2:

```
newprice3= soup.find('span', class_ = 'sc-1p4en3j-7 eHDQUL')
print (str(newprice3))
```

output:

```
None
None
None
None
```

Comment: Is there some reasoun you don't use proper API? Parsing some values from website is always risky because they can change something on their site without any warning and then your script doesn't work anymore.  It seems that they have https://api.binance.com/

Comment: Using chrome's inspect on that element, i can see that the classname is auto-generated as it gets changed every time the value changes. This basically means that you won't be able to use the classname to gather info here. What you could do, albeit a lot dumber is access each div in the source in the order that it appears... This would actually work better in this case. Your only other option is an API, as in the comment from ex4.

Comment: thanks guys, as you said I should use API Binance...I just used it as mentioned in answer 1... it worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use BeautifulSoup to retrieve the price directly from the website because it's being generated using javascript and updated via web-sockets, you should use the free [Binance API](https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md) instead.
Here's an example to retrieve the `LTCUSDT` price:

```
import requests
url = "https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol=LTCUSDT"
resp = requests.get(url).json()
price = resp['price']
# 43.45000000
```

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/9cf86a7335)

Comment: Yes its better to use api if available

Comment: Here is documentation for the API: https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md